# How can I access variables that are named sequentially by a loop while still inside of the loop?

Tags: bash, variables, loops, eval

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to create a set of variables that are numbered based on another variable (using eval) in a loop, and then call on it before the loop ends.

As an example I've written a script called question (The fist command is to show what is the contents of the variable $tab)

```
(23:32:12\[deco@S.Man)
[~/bin]$ listQpsk 40|grep -w [1-4]
40 SMANHUBAQPSK1          1    1344      1195        88
40 SMANHUBAQPSK1          2    1668      1470        88
40 SMANHUBAQPSK1          3    1881      1539        81
40 SMANHUBAQPSK1          4    1686      1409        83


(23:18:42\[deco@S.Man)
[~/bin]$ cat question
#!/usr/bin/bash
tab=`listQpsk 40|grep -w [1-4]`
seq=1
num=4
until [[ $seq -gt $num ]];do
eval count$seq=`echo "$tab"|grep -w $seq|awk '{print $5}'`
seq=$(($seq+1))
done
echo $count1
echo $count2
echo $count3
echo $count4
```

When I run this I get

```
(23:32:23\[deco@S.Man)
[~/bin]$ ./question 
1195
1471
1538
1409
```

Which is exactly what I would expect, but is there a way to move the echo commands inside of the until loop so that part of the loop is echoing the value of the variable that was just created. Something like:

```
until [[ $seq -gt $num ]];do
eval count$seq=`echo "$tab"|grep -w $seq|awk '{print $5}'`
seq=$(($seq+1))
echo "$count$seq"
done
```

PS: Sorry if my formatting is off...first time posting here, and I only know markdown from reddit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use indirection:

```
until [[ $seq -gt $num ]];do
    var="count$seq"
    eval $var=$(echo "$tab"|awk -v seq=$seq '$3==seq {print $5}') # awk loves to do grep's job
    let seq+=1    # another way
    echo "${!var}"    # indirection
done
```

No need for another eval.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I'm not sure I understand the indirection part though. But it worked both the way you wrote it and just as echo $var

Comment: echo $var would give "count1", for example. echo ${!var} gives the contents of the contents of var which would be "1195". echo ${!var} works similarly to echo $(eval echo \$$var)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly answering your question, but... did you know bash has array variables?

```
seq=1
num=4
until [[ $seq -gt $num ]];do
count[$seq]=`echo "$tab"|grep -w $seq|awk '{print $5}'`
seq=$(($seq+1))
done
echo ${count[*]}
```

Or without arrays:

```
seq=1
num=4
until [[ $seq -gt $num ]];do
eval count$seq=`echo "$tab"|grep -w $seq|awk '{print $5}'`
eval echo \$count$seq
seq=$(($seq+1))
done
```

Comment: I'm aware of them, but I haven't really started working them into scripts yet. 0 Formal training + full time work as a sysadmin means that I generally have to learn new skills as I have a need for them. I try not to get too far ahead of myself, because I worry I won't absorb it. 

Awesome reply though. Seeing the array syntax in something I already mostly understand is a huge help in my general understanding.

Other than cleanliness, is there an advantage in this instance? It's still the same amount of built-ins vs external commands no?

Comment: I would consider it the "right" way to do this. However, the syntax can get kind of ugly, as evidenced by the `echo` statement. Without arrays you have to throw more evals at it (as per cma's answer). BTW, I've read the `man bash` page a dozen times top to bottom and I still find a new awesome "where have you been all my life" feature every time I read it again. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
varName=a
for i in 1 2 3
do
   eval $varName$i=stuff
   eval var=\$$varName$i
   echo $var
done
```

some versions of shell also let you use ${!var} to indirectly reference variables

Comment: Ah oops, fixed so it does what he wants now :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like this (in bash at least):

```
$ count1=xyz
$ seq=1
$ value=`eval echo \$\{count$seq\}`
$ echo $value
```